# Windows 10- Touch pad gestures- Zed-iLife notebook

Tags: windows-10, windows-8, touchpad, gestures

I have a notebook. its super small so it's irritating to use a small touchpad gestures popping up inadvertently.
I have scoured various "mouse" settings.. No option for gesture control. No specific OEM software to control gesture or any touchpad settings for that matter. 
Any help much appreciated.

It's a zed mini manufactured by iLife.
http://i-life.us/product/zedair-mini/

Comment: The best way to disable touchpad gestures is either uninstall the touchpad drivers itself, or if your touchpad implements the hardware capability required, disabled the gestures within Windows 10.

Comment: any body found the answer?